# Unexpected Unexpected token t in JSON at position 6 AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am writing a simple `lambda` function which uses a post request to insert some data into `DynamoDB` However after deploying the lambda function I keep getting a `502 Bad Gateway` in postman when I try to test the function.

I tried debugging in `AWS` via `API Gateway` which returns the following stack trace.

`Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorType":"SyntaxError","errorMessage":"Unexpected token t in JSON at position 6","trace":["SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 6","    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)","    at Runtime.module.exports.createPost [as handler] (/var/task/handler.js:16:24)","    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"]}`

However, I am not sure where exactly the JSON has a syntax error.

This is the example request

```
curl --location --request POST 'https:localhosttest:3000/dev/post' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"title": "POST One TEST",
"body": "This is the first post"
}'
```

and this is my code

```
"use strict";
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: "2012-08-10" });
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

const postsTable = process.env.POSTS_TABLE;

const response = (statusCode, message) => {
  return {
    statusCode,
    body: JSON.stringify(message),
  };
};

module.exports.createPost = (event, context, callback) => {
  const reqBody = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const post = {
    id: uuidv4,
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    userId: 1,
    title: reqBody.title,
    body: reqBody.body
  };

  return db
    .put({
      TableName: postsTable,
      Item: post
    })
    .promise()
    .then(() => {
      callback(null, response(201, post));
    })
    .catch((err) => response(null, response(err.statusCode, err)));
};
```

when I `console.log` the `event.body`  I see the following:

```
{
    "title": "POST One TEST",
    "body": "This is the first post"
}
```

and the stack trace I can see in `cloudwatch` is

```
ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "SyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "Unexpected token t in JSON at position 6",
    "stack": [
        "SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 6",
        "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
        "    at Runtime.module.exports.createPost [as handler] (/var/task/handler.js:17:24)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you `console.log(event.body)` before trying to parse it and see what you're actually getting? also try `--data-raw '{"title":"POST One TEST","body":"This is the first post"}'` - i.e. one line

Comment: @JaromandaX please see the update above

Comment: well, that's not JSON .... JSON would be `{"title":"POST One TEST","body":"This is the first post"}` - see how the object keys are inside `" "`

Comment: and, see how the value that body is nothing like the data you claim you've sent in the curl ...

Comment: sorry that was an error on my side, I have updated it now

Comment: well, if that's the body, then where did the indentation before `"title"` come from? it's not in your request - the 7th character in your request is more likely to be the letter `l` or the second `t` maybe, but in your ORIGINAL console.log output, that would produce the exact error you are getting  ... have you tried a single line like I suggested? `--data-raw '{"title":"POST One TEST","body":"This is the first post"}'`

Comment: see, I think you really are sending `{\n    title: "....etc` because the {, linefeed character, 4 spaces, ... then the `t` is at position:6 ... exactly what the error is saying

Comment: tried sending it as --data-raw '{"title":"POST One TEST","body":"This is the first post"}' still getting the same error

Answer (score 3):

event.body is already of type object, because of that you might be getting error.

Or console the type of event, body to debug properly.

You can do something like below:

```
const reqBody = typeof event.body === 'string' ? JSON.parse(event.body) : event.body;
```

Comment: tried the above suggestion and still getting the same error

Comment: What is the type of body, is it showing? Instead of --data-raw, can you try --data or -d only for a post request?

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues that needed to be fixed. The first issue was that, when sending the post request using Postman, my request was being indented automatically hence the initial error which correctly identified by `jaromanda-x`. Sending everything in one line did the trick.

After fixing that error I was getting an error complaining about id not being set. This was because in my `post` object I had `id:uuidv4` instead of `id:uuidv4()`